# How to append to a csv using pandas such that the headers are ordered correctly

Tags: python, pandas, csv

When appending to a csv it's required that the columns are in the correct order, as far as I can tell at least.

Example:

```py
data_store = pd.DataFrame(columns=["a", "b", "c"])
data_store.to_csv("data_storage.csv", index=False)
new_data = pd.DataFrame({"b": ["bb"], "c": ["cc"], "a": ["aa"]})
new_data.to_csv("data_storage.csv", mode="a", header=False)
check = pd.read_csv("./data_storage.csv")
```

Which outputs:

```
print(check)
    a   b   c
0  bb  cc  aa
```

Clearly here I wanted to have `aa` with column `a`, and so on. But I'm not sure how I can do this unless I just sort the dataframe alphabetically, and ensure the csv is sorted alphabetically too.

Answer (score 2):

You should just force *some* order in your data-frame columns. Like you did when you initialized `data_store = pd.DataFrame(columns=["a", "b", "c"])`. It doesn't have to be alphabetical, but you could use:

```
new_data = pd.DataFrame({"b": ["bb"], "c": ["cc"], "a": ["aa"]}, columns=['a','b','c'])
```